# How does glassfish use ManagedObjectManagers?

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

Does anyone know how glassfish uses ManagedObjectManagers? I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/gmbal/ManagedObjectManager
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:174)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:602)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:308)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
at project.CollectionManagementService.getCollectionManagementPort(CollectionManagementService.java:55)
```

when I call the following method:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "CollectionManagementPort")
public CollectionManagement getCollectionManagementPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://project/", "CollectionManagementPort"), CollectionManagement.class);
}
```

and I'm trying to figure out what's going on. I don't actively use ManagedObjectManagers in the code I've written, so I am wondering how they are used in an attempt to solve the NoClassDefFoundError. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is a gmbal.jar in glassfish\modules. Adding this to the project's build path removes the NoClassDefFoundError.